# Ordering test cases in Botium

Tags: testing, botframework, chatbot

I am exploring Botium for my internal project. I have a set of test cases (*.convo.txt files) which are placed in convo folder. I have below queries:

1. In which order test cases are picked from convo folder?
2. If it is possible to skip some test cases present in convo folder?
3. Can we define user specified test case ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The test cases are retrieved from the convo folder recursivly and order by convo name (first line in the convo file) on execution. You are encouraged to find a taxanomy for naming test cases based on alphabetical sort order.
2. no, currently not
3. no, currently not

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any plan to include support for question 2 and 3 in Botium?

Comment: 2. is already in our backlog and there will be solution, as soon as it's priority is high enough to make it into a sprint (with each request, the priority rises ...). 3. is more tricky, how could a feature as this look like ?